# Determining most recent time stamp between two values with the same ID

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code that queries the below data table that lists a couple `Case IDs` and each has a number of time stamps associated with status changes. I need to pull `First Contact Resolution` and `Resolved` and then select the one with the most recent time stamp of the two. I attempted this with a CTE and using `MAX()` but it's still providing `CASE IDs` with both `First Contact Resolution` and `Resolved` statuses. Where am I going wrong?

```
WITH most_recent_status (Status, CaseId, TimeStamp) AS (
    SELECT
        svb_newvalue,
        svb_caseid,
        svb_timestamp
    FROM Table1
    WHERE svb_newvalue IN ('First Contact Resolution','Resolved')
)

SELECT
    CaseId [Case ID],
    MAX(TimeStamp) [Time Stamp],
    Status
    FROM
        most_recent_status
GROUP BY CaseId, TimeStamp, Status
```

Data table:

| Case ID | Time Stamp | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6045BD006793 | 7/27/23 15:19 | Resolved |
| 6045BD006793 | 7/26/23 17:32 | First Contact Resolution |
| 6045BD006793 | 7/27/23 15:17 | Active |
| 6045BD006239 | 7/18/23 17:46 | Pending Internal |
| 6045BD006239 | 7/18/23 17:57 | Routed |
| 6045BD006239 | 7/18/23 18:03 | First Contact Resolution |
| 6045BD006239 | 7/18/23 19:19 | Routed |
| 6045BD006239 | 7/18/23 16:36 | Resolved |
| 6045BD006239 | 7/18/23 16:05 | Routed |

The Resulting table:

| Case ID | Time Stamp | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6045BD006793 | 7/27/23 15:19 | Resolved |
| 6045BD006793 | 7/26/23 17:32 | First Contact Resolution |
| 6045BD006239 | 7/18/23 18:03 | First Contact Resolution |
| 6045BD006239 | 7/18/23 16:36 | Resolved |

What should happen:

| Case ID | Time Stamp | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6045BD006793 | 7/27/23 15:19 | Resolved |
| 6045BD006239 | 7/18/23 18:03 | First Contact Resolution |

Comment: If you GROUP BY Case ID, Timestamp and Status, then you're inherently telling SQL to treat rows with different values in those fields as separate rows (and therefore assess any aggregate, like MAX(), on those individual rows).  Therefore, the rows that you are trying to aggregate/collapse, will never aggregate

Comment: Say that you happened to have two rows, for the same Case ID, with the same Timestamp - but one row is "Resolved" and one row is "First Contact Resolution" - which status would you expect to see, in that instance?

Comment: @Craig Very valid question. I'm assuming OP is thinking because they're using `MAX()` on the `TimeStamp` column, they'll get the row with the `Status` that matches that `TimeStamp`. That's probably their misconception here. If so, then there's a few easy solutions.

Comment: @J.D. That is precisely what I thought was happening - if I used `MAX()` then it would automatically choose the latest timestamp and the associated status along with it, but it seems my understanding of this mechanism is poor.

Comment: @Craig In this instance `First Contact Resolution` and `Resolved` cannot have the same time stamp so I would only be looking for the one that came last (or most recent).

Comment: @J.D. What would those easy solutions be? Would I remove the `CaseID` from the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @hobosapien I'll try to post and answer to explain when I get a chance (or maybe someone can post one before me). My go-to for a problem where you want the latest row of a *grouping* is using something called a window function. I'll elaborate in my answer.

Comment: @hobosapien - in my experience, the one thing that you think CAN'T happen in your data is invariably the one thing that WILL happen (and usually when it's least needed!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script. Keep in mind that Craig has a good point and you might want to add that to the query.

```
WITH cte
AS (SELECT
             t.svb_caseid,
             MAX(t.svb_timestamp) AS LastTimeStamp
    FROM     @Table1 AS t
    WHERE    t.svb_newvalue IN ( 'First Contact Resolution', 'Resolved' )
    GROUP BY t.svb_caseid)
SELECT
     a.svb_caseid AS [Case ID],
     a.svb_timestamp AS [Time Stamp],
     a.svb_newvalue AS [Status]
FROM cte AS c
     CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT   TOP (1)
                             t.svb_caseid,
                             t.svb_timestamp,
                             t.svb_newvalue
                    FROM     @Table1 AS t
                    WHERE    t.svb_caseid = c.svb_caseid
                             AND t.svb_timestamp = c.LastTimeStamp
                             AND t.svb_newvalue IN ( 'First Contact Resolution', 'Resolved' )
                    ORDER BY t.svb_newvalue ASC
                 /*Add logic to see which is more important*/
                 ) a;
```